# Show that $\mu:=\sum_{i\geq 1}p_i\mu_i$ is a probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

> > Let $(\mu_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of probability mesaures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ and $(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ a probability vector. Show that then $\mu:=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p_i\mu_i$ defines a probability measure.

Hello, here is my proof:

It is $\mu(\emptyset)=\sum_{i\geq 1}p_i\mu_i(\emptyset)=0$, because $\mu_i(\emptyset)=0, i\geq 1$. Similarly it is $\mu(\Omega)=\sum_{i\geq 1}p_i\mu_i(\Omega)=\sum_{i\geq 1}p_i=1$, because $\mu_i(\Omega)=1, i\geq 1$.

Let $A_i,i\geq 1$ pairwise disjoint in $\mathcal{A}$. Set $A:=\bigcup_{i\geq 1}A_i$.
$$
\mu(A)=\sum_{i\geq 1}p_i\mu_i(A)=\sum_{i\geq 1}p_i(\sum_{j\geq 1}\mu_i(A_j))=\sum_{i\geq 1}\sum_{j\geq 1}p_i\mu_i(A_j)=\sum_{j\geq 1}\sum_{i\geq 1}p_i\mu_i(A_j)=\sum_{i\geq 1}\mu(A_i).
$$

Is it okay?

Miro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. You should probably note that you may interchange the two sums, since the terms are non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Correct proof. However:

You better use index $j$ by defining $A$ as disjoint union. This because index $i$ is allready in use. This results in: $$\mu\left(A\right)=\sum_{i}p_{i}\mu_{i}\left(A\right)=\sum_{i}p_{i}\sum_{j}\mu_{i}\left(A_{j}\right)=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}p_{i}\mu_{i}\left(A_{j}\right)=\sum_{j}\sum_{i}p_{i}\mu_{i}\left(A_{j}\right)=\sum_{j}\mu\left(A_{j}\right)$$

Note that your last expression inconsistently has index $i$.